# Определение положения курсора в текстовом поле

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как реализовать следующею задачу: есть текстареа и допустим несколько инпутов, в текстареа отредактировали текст и нажали на инпут, в то место, где был курсор, в текстареа должно добавиться значение инпута (здесь на хэш коде похожий функционал)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<textarea id="qwerty"></textarea>
<input id="add" value="CoB" type="button">
```

jQuery

```
$('#add').bind('click', function(){
    var ta = $('#qwerty'),
        p = ta[0].selectionStart,
        text = ta.val();
     if(p != undefined)
         ta.val(text.slice(0, p) + $(this).val() + text.slice(p));
     else{
         ta.trigger('focus');
         range = document.selection.createRange();
         range.text = $(this).val();
     }
});
```

Comment: не точно определяет расположение курсора, если есть перевод строки, а курсор расположен перед переводом строки (в конце слова например) то значение инпута вставляется после перевода строки

Comment: а вот если нет перевода строк то всё работает, но без них никак

Comment: Код подправил, но только птому что ie неадекватен, скажи в каком браузере у тебя такая фигня